# cannot read from remote repository gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, smartgit

I use smartgit for git pull and push.it was working fine earlier but I don't know what happened it is giving me an error

> "can't read from repository".

then,I tried from windows cmd and it was showing me an error like

> Warning: the RSA host key for 'myVP1' differs from the key for the IP address 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx'
> Offending key for IP in /home/mano/.ssh/known_hosts:1
> Matching host key in /home/mano/.ssh/known_hosts:2
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

please help me to find the solution.how to add the new host key to resolve smartgit problem please help me

[this error I was getting from smartgit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iljJg.png)

Comment: Looks like they changed their host key... and you can choose whether or not you want to accept the new one. Have you tried doing so?

Comment: yes, when i was committing, new host key was added in the known_host file. but, when I tried to pull from smartgit , it gave me the error I mentioned above

Comment: I believe the tag [tag:git] is not appropriate here: the issue is a networking issue, and has little to do with either [tag:git] or arguably [tag:gitlab], but rather [tag:smartgit] if any.

Answer (score -3):

I have deleted the offending IP address it was giving, and then enter the command in cmd
git pull origin master

then again tried to pull form smartgit. the error resolved and when I did the commit the key added.

Comment: I don't see this answer or question being useful for anyone else. Just delete it.